# Check for empty username or password on login

Tags: users, login, password, authentication

I'm building a custom login page for clients and wish to keep the wp-login page for site administrators.

For checking for empty fields I'm using the code:

```
function verify_user_pass($user, $username, $password) {
    $login_page  = home_url('/login/');
    if($username == "" || $password == "") {
        wp_redirect($login_page . "?login=empty");
        exit;
    }
}
add_filter('authenticate', 'verify_user_pass', 1, 3);
```

But this is interfering with the wp-login, as it checks to early and redirects to the "client login page" right after landing on the wp-login page.

Is there any other approach for checking empty fields that doesn't interfere with the wp-login?

Thank you!

Comment: This filter does not return, filters always return. This is the same as adding `return null;` to the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is you've set the priority of your filter to "1" which means it will run first.  Since `authenticate` is going to run on any login (wp-login.php or your front-end login page), you probably need to start with setting it to the default (10). Otherwise, it's just going to hijack your wp-login.php.

Since you don't need to do this on wp-login.php, you could also check to make sure that's not the current page when you run your custom validation.  I did that in your function by checking the global 'pagenow' is not 'wp-login.php'.

```
function verify_user_pass( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' ) {
        $login_page  = home_url( 'login/' );
        if ( "" == $username || "" == $password ) {
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'login', 'empty', $login_page ) );
            exit();
        }
    }

    return $user;
}
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'verify_user_pass', 10, 3 );
```

Some other things I changed:

- `home_url()` does not need a leading slash for slugs - it will put that in automatically.
- changed your comparisons to "yoda conditions" (`"" == $username`) - it's a good habit to get into because it catches type/syntax errors (like if you mistype "`=`" instead of "`==`").
- use `add_query_arg()` to add your query argument to the URL. That way it will be added properly, even if there are other query arguments in the URL.
- Note that this is a filter, not an action. Therefore, you need to make sure you return what the filter hook is filtering. In the case of `authenticate` that's the `$user` object (which may also contain a `WP_Error` object). If you don't return this at the end, you'll break anything outside your custom process that also runs this filter (i.e. the main wp-login.php).

Comment: The conditional check for current page is making the function not work correctly. When at the custom login page, any empty field will make the page redirect to the wp-login page.

Comment: My original answer was to change the priority, but as I continued writing it I added the conditional check. With the conditional check in place, you may actually be successful setting the priority back to 1. However, since we're only looking at one piece of a full process that is kind of out of context, that's hard to say for certain.  You're not actually using `authenticate` as a filter, but as an action. So you may actually be better off checking for empty fields prior to starting WP's login process (assuming you're firing `wp_signon()` hooked to `init` or something similar).

Comment: It doesn't help setting the priority back to 1. All I'm doing is basically what's described in this article ([link](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-loginpage/)), without the redirection from the `wp-login.php` page to the new custom login page.